# Continuity of operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

Let $(T_t)_{t \ge0}$ be a family of operators(not necessarily bounded, but all defined on the same domain) and now we have the property

$$t \rightarrow 0^+ \Rightarrow ||T_t^2 -T_0^2|| \rightarrow 0$$

Does this mean that we also have $||T_t - T_0|| \rightarrow 0$ for $t \rightarrow 0^+$?

Comment: That's not true even for two numbers: $a^2 = b^2$ does not imply $a=b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample with operators $\Bbb R^2\longrightarrow\Bbb R^2$: $T_0=$identity, $T_t$=rotation of 180 degrees for $t>0$.